# How to eliminate duplicate IPs from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble trying to find a solution to remove duplicate IPs from a text file.

I have a text file which contains the following lines (basically, it is an extract from A DNS server):

```
123.example.com. A 142.10.54.87
random.domain.com. A 142.10.54.87
test.foo.com. A 153.54.21.2
abc.example.com. A 142.10.54.87
test2.example.com. A 20.54.32.6
test1.example.com. A 20.54.32.6
1457.example.com. A 142.10.54.87
test.example.com. A 20.54.32.6
```

As you can see:

1. the IP address 142.10.54.87 is mentionned 4 times
2. the IP address 20.54.32.6 is mentionned 3 times
3. the IP address 20.54.32.6 is mentionned 1 time

I would like to create a shell script (or a python script) which takes the file as an input and remove duplicates IP (whatever IP, not only those in this example), when they are found more than 2 times, **but keep the first 2 occurences**.

So, the desired output would be:

```
123.example.com. A 142.10.54.87
random.domain.com. A 142.10.54.87
test.foo.com. A 153.54.21.2
test2.example.com. A 20.54.32.6
test1.example.com. A 20.54.32.6
```

Do you have any ideas how I could achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? I would have a Python script create a new file, and while iterating over the items in the original file copy them into the second file only if they match your criteria. Put the IPs in a map (dict) with a per-IP counter. But that is just an opinion.

Comment: I tried using shell commands, basically using grep with a regexp to create a list of all IPs in the file then using "sort -u" to remove duplicate IPs. Then I was planning to use this file to search for duplicate IPs in the DNS export file and remove lines when the count was greater than 2 for a particular IP. I was struggling with this last part. From the replies below, I understand that python is probably a better choice than a shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
fileDesc = open(INPUT_FILE_NAME,'r')
fileData = fileDesc.read()
fileDesc.close()

IPs = {}
for line in fileData.splitlines():
    words = line.split(' ')
    IP = words[2]
    if IP not in IPs:
        IPs[IP] = [words]
    elif len(IPs[IP]) < 2:
        IPs[IP].append(words)

lines = []
for IP in IPs:
    for words in IPs[IP]:
        lines.append(' '.join(words))

fileDesc = open(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,'w')
fileDesc.write('\n'.join(lines))
fileDesc.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with pandas in python. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the data file with a space as separator.
# Add some column names
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep="\s+", header=None)
df.columns = ['host', 'record', 'ip']

# Keep the first occurence, drop it from the dataframe, then keep the second occurence
df_first = df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'ip')
df_withoutFirst = df.drop(index = df_first.index)
df_second = df_withoutFirst.drop_duplicates(subset = 'ip')

# Merge the results and sort by IP
df_result = pd.concat([df_first, df_second]).sort_values(by="ip")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution would be:

```
f = '''123.example.com. A 142.10.54.87
random.domain.com. A 142.10.54.87
test.foo.com. A 153.54.21.2
abc.example.com. A 142.10.54.87
test2.example.com. A 20.54.32.6
test1.example.com. A 20.54.32.6
1457.example.com. A 142.10.54.87
test.example.com. A 20.54.32.6
test.example.com. A 20.54.32.6
test.example.com. A 20.54.32.6'''

f = f.split('\n')

dc = {}
max_number = 2
for l in f:
    d, l, ip = l.split(' ')
    if ip in dc.keys():
        if dc[ip]['counter'] < max_number and d not in dc[ip].keys():
            dc[ip][d] = (l,ip)
            dc[ip]['counter'] = dc[ip]['counter'] +1
        else:
            pass
    else:
        dc[ip] = {}
        dc[ip][d] = (l, ip)
        dc[ip]['counter'] = 1

for k,v in dc.items():
    counter =0
    for ki in dc[k].keys():
        if ki != 'counter':
            counter +=1
            l, ip = dc[k][ki]
            print(' '.join([ki,l, ip, str(counter)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Store lines in an array `full`, when the third word has occured at most twice.

```
awk 'ip[$3]++<2 {full[n++]=$0 }
     END  { for (i=0;i<n;i++) { print full[i] } }
    ' testfile
```